# Is there anyway to provide default value to a boolean comparison involving optionals in Swift?

Tags: swift, comparison, option-type

The logic behind optional is to give default action if the value is nil. I usually give default value in conditional evaluating as a substitute instead of force unwrap a variable, such as:

```
var test : Bool?;
test = resultOfSomeFunction();
if test ?? false { doThis(); } else { failMiserably(); }
```

Or

```
var name : String?
name = resultOfSomeFunction();
if (name ?? "") == "Plato" { youAreAPhilosopher(); } else { youAreOrdinaryMan(); }
```

Or

```
enum CarType { case alphard; case jaguar; case bwm; case mercedes; case none; }
var carType : CarType?;
carType = resultOfSomeFunction();
if (carType ?? .none) == .jaguar { rideThisCar(); } else { sellThisCar(); }
```

But for the last type, this kind of coding gets weird because I have to provide a special case `.none` in order for this default value to works. So I'm thinking, can somebody create comparison methods (==, <=, >=, <, >, !=, &&, ||) that can take optionals and return ***optional bool***, and if any of the side of the operator is nil, the comparison will return ***nil***? So I want to change the comparison into like this:

```
enum CarType { case alphard; case jaguar; case bwm; case mercedes; case none; }
var carType : CarType?;
carType = resultOfSomeFunction();
if (carType == .jaguar) ?? false { rideThisCar(); } else { sellThisCar(); }
```

I think this is a more straightforward way to read the code than the previous one, and this can really shorten some of my code:

```
if let startDate = objectStartDate, 
    let endDate = objectEndDate, 
    startDate < Date,
    Date < endDate {
    promotionIsActive();
}
else { promotionExpired(); }
```

Becomes:

```
if ((startDate < Date) && (Date < endDate)) ?? false {
    promotionIsActive();
}
else { promotionExpired(); }
```

I have seen some code somewhere that tackle optional comparison, but it forces the result of the comparison into non-optional bool. I need the optional so I can provide my own default action. Thanks.

Comment: FYI - `==` works with optionals so your 1st example becomes `if test == true { doThis() } else { fail() }`. No need for the use of `??`. If `test` is `nil` then it's treated as `false`. And with the `enum` you don't need the `.none` value.

Comment: @rmaddy I've just tried it and indeed it does not! I must have confused it with the optional integer or string comparison then. Thanks, at least some of the issues are tackled!

Comment: Using `==` with optionals works for any data type, not just `Bool`. But you can't use optionals with `<` or `>`.

Comment: Xcode 9 gives me this after converting to Swift 4
```swift
// FIXME: comparison operators with optionals were removed from the Swift Standard Libary.
// Consider refactoring the code to use the non-optional operators.
fileprivate func < <T : Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
  switch (lhs, rhs) {
  case let (l?, r?):
    return l < r
  case (nil, _?):
    return true
  default:
    return false
  }
}
```